# angular, strip unused data before doing a lodash _.isEqual

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

So I have am trying to compare 2 objects using lodash's `_.isEqual` method, I have pretty straight forward function that checks like so

```
function findMatchingQuery(savedSearch) {  
       if (_.isEqual(savedSearch.data.document.query, $scope.searchResults.minify())) {
             return true;
       }
}
```

The data has changed a bit and I need to pull out a piece of data inside before I do a compare.

So the each of those objects has this format -

```
{
   "name": "item name",
   "showMore": boolean,
   "filters": []
}
```

And what I would like to do is strip out the `showMore` node. I tried to add the some vars using `_.remove`, however it seems this does not work because remove is looking for a key and value.

```
 var modifiedSavedSearch =  _.remove(savedSearch.data.document.query, { "showMore" });
 var modifiedCurrentSearch =  _.remove($scope.searchResults.minify(), { "showMore" });
```

Is there a simple way to strip away those parts of the object before running the `_.isEqual` on them? Doesn't have to be lodash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, [omit](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) should do what you are looking for:

```
var modifiedSavedSearch =  _.omit(savedSearch.data.document.query, { "showMore" });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the attribute, like:

`delete savedSearch.data.document.query.showMore`

You can use `_.omit` to remove it, or you can use `_.pick` to pick the rest of the attributes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of it completely, you can do the following:

```
// assuming this is your variable
var myVar = {
   "name": "item name",
   "showMore": boolean,
   "filters": []
};

// delete the unwanted property
delete myVar.showMore;
```